# Are you able to use the iPhone calendar data in the iphone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, calendar

I dont think you are allowed to create your own calendar on an app, since historically they get rejected with 'Duplicates functionality of iPhone OS' message.

So, can you import the users calendar and display it?

And if so, can someone post a link to a tutorial or something please?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API in the iPhone SDK that allows insertion of viewing of calendar information

Comment: Yeah, but you can see their point - I think it's more of a privacy thing, than a functionality dupe issue.  Imagine the stuff that could 'leak'

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't allow access to the calendar, similar to how there is no way to access the SMS database. I think their reasoning is that they don't want to give people the ability to write a basic functionality app to replace the phone's default app.

Maybe not though, because there is an address book API.

Edit: Since this writing, I believe with iOS 3.0 or 4.0, there is a calendar API in iOS.